# @AuthenticationPrincipal and HandlerMethodArgumentResolver interface

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security, annotations

I am trying to understand the usecase of @AuthenticationPrincipal.

In my controller, I have an method where I use as a parameter

`@AuthenticationPrincipal User user`

The objective is to get a user from a jwt, so I have created a resolver class which is implementing HandlerMethodArgumentResolver. For the supportsParameters it is my User class, and my resolveArgument get the jwt from the webRequest, decode it and create a User object, this one is returned (And used in my controller method).

I have tried to remove @AuthenticationPrincipal because I am not using the Principal in my class which implements HandlerMethodArgumentResolver, it works perfectly but according to my research it is "very advised" to use this annotation even if it works without.

Does someone know why and how exactly in this case it is/isn't necessary to use @AuthenticationPrincipal, it will help me to have a better comprehension about it ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you need to implement `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` to resolve `@AuthenticationPrincipal` ? Spring security already shipped with an implementation called `AuthenticationPrincipalArgumentResolver` for doing such thing and will be enable by default.

As long as you customize the `Authentication` to contain your user object and store it to the `SecurityContext` after spring security successfully authenticate an user , it should work out of the box.

The only situation you need to implement a `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` is that you are not using spring security but want to specify an user object for the current user as an argument in the controller method. If that is the case , you don't need to annotate `@AuthenticationPrincipal` in the controller 's argument as your implementation is nothing do with it.

Comment: I am using Spring Security and logging in users with JWT tokens.
I want to prevent some users from accessing paths they're not allowed to.
For example, if a user with id 17 accesses .../data?userId=33, he shouldn't be allowed to do so. In this case, I have to compare the userId from the JWT with the userId in the request and see if there is a match.

Comment: okay, then configure the spring security properly such that the `Authentication` contains your use object correctly , and then just use the `@AuthenticationPrincipal` in the controller method. no need to implement your own HandlerMethodArgumentResolver

Comment: That is correct. When I am verifying my JWT, if it is valid, I set my Authentication object in my SecurityContextHolder with the information provided in the JWT (the user, in this case). Finally, I just have to compare the user in the Authentication (set with filter) with the userId of the request. Thank you.

Comment: ok. then do you find my answer is helpful to you ? if yes , would you please consider to upvote it or accept it as i spend many time to help you for free. cheers.